Book about a boy traveling to another world through a bag
Looking for a book where the main character, a boy, has a satchel/book bag made of leather maybe, and travels to another world through it. Also another entrance to the world is through this old man's shop. They also keep their gold and coins in the bags. Characters carry staffs as well. Magic? Quest. Journey. Visiting different shops in the world looking for something.
Maybe a trilogy? The second book has a green cover.

In roughly which year/s did you read these books?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Through the bag? You mean, like Newt Scamander climbing into his suitcase?

Read possibly middle school -Highschool. So 2007-2014.
Yes, through the bag like Newt Scama neder climbing through his suitcase.

i've been looking for this same series for so long and your question was the only lead i had for a while. finally found it just now and came back to share with you. it's the:
Adventurers Wanted Series by M. L. Forman.


Boy finds shop with a strange sign calling for adventurers. He acquires a magic bag that he can travel into and out of, newt style, and holds the party's gold and items in it. He travels to and from the other world through the old man's shop as well as through the bag. Third book, not second, has green cover.


Unlikely to be correct given the lack of details, but based on the year range OP read it, this might be The wardstone chronicles and specifically book 3 instead of book 2:

The chronicles were released from 2004 - 2013 and a few of the other books also have green covers (depending on which edition). In terms of plot, the main character is a boy who travels round as an apprentice to "the spook" to learn and help deal with the dark arts like witches and ghost. The pair travel the land fairly frequently and always carry staffs (with a hidden blade) for protection and a satchel filled with a notebook, any money and a small amount of food.

Yeah not it, there is a whole fantasy world in the book bag that the characters go into, then once in the world the bag is used to store gold/coins/supplies.
